# Read / Write Data NSCoding iOS - Singelton or Not?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, singleton, nscoding

This has been asked many times, but I'm still at a crossroads.

My application is required to save data, this data can be accessed through many areas of the application.

I wanted to avoid core data as it is overkill for what I need to save 3-4 simple different  classes.

So I’m using NSCoding, and its working without issue.

Im not stuck on whats the “best” way to access this stored data.

Essentially, singleton or not. Been reading a variety of posts and most say avoid the use of a singleton.

This issue became apparent as my current design uses a singlelton object to provide a way for me to access my data from disc easily. Problem is testing… couldn’t find a way to overcome the inability to test - this is when I decided to ask should i not be using this pattern.

So, what is the better way to access my data - to allow read and write from anyplace within my application.

Use the singleton and just don’t test - or create a new instance, and ask that instance to retrieve my data. I also don’t want to pass data along - I want to be able to easily access data - read and write (using tab bar controller etc)

This was my singleton implementation

```
class InvalidClientCollection {

    static var errorList = InvalidClientCollection.loadErrataClients()
    static private let kErrataClientSaveFileName = "errorClientsFile"

    static var clientCount:Int {
        get {
            return errorList.count
        }
    }

    static func loadErrataClients() -> [Client] {

        let mysavefile = FilePath(fileName: kErrataClientSaveFileName).filePath
        if let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(mysavefile) as? [Client] {
            return data
        }
        return [Client]()
    }

    static func saveErrataClientList() {
        let mysavefile = FilePath(fileName: kErrataClientSaveFileName).filePath
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(errorList, toFile: mysavefile)
    }
}
```

Should I redesign, so to get my data I would

```
let mycolleection = InvalidClientCollection()
let mystuff = mycollection.errorList
```

I guess something like this ?

```
class InvalidClientCollection {

    var errorList:[Client] {
        get {
           return loadErrataClients()
        }
        set {
            self.errorList = newValue
            // maybe even save at same time
            //saveErrataClientList()
        }
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Any ideas - improved code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, avoiding a singleton for this is a good plan. One simple solution is to create a single instance of your data class and keep a reference as a property in the app delegate. It's easy to access the app delegate from any class. Then from there you can access the property. This eliminates the singleton and makes testing easier.

Another option is to pass the needed data instance to each of your view controllers in the app. This has the benefit of not assuming there is only one data instance needed by the app. This can start in the app delegate by passing the data instance to the root view controller. Then the root controller can pass it on to any view controller it presents or pushes, etc. This is made easier by subclassing `UIViewController` and having all of your view controller extend your base class. A `UIViewController` category is even better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the first suggestion sounds easier. In regards to the seconds solution, I’m concerned that having each VC having its own instance of data will be a constant struggle to keep it all in sync. (which i found initially and then had the so called bright idea of a single shared global). For example, if I alter my data in VC “X”, I want the data in VC “A” to match - having the data in the singleton solved this automatically. I see how this is similar to storing the data in the app delegate.

Comment: As long as you pass along the same reference to each view controller, there is nothing to keep up-to-date. A change to that one reference will be reflected everywhere.

Comment: true. I was just a bit messy passing between Tabs in my TabBarController. I have gone with option one, and works well... and is testable!! Now I'm wondering if I should be concerned with NSCoding Read / Write frequency ... as I'm saving out an entire array each time.